# High-Gain Common Emitter Circuit

Tags: amplifier, bjt, gain, bypass

I am trying to design a high-gain common emitter circuit. I know that I need to use a bypass capacitor with emitter resistor to increase the gain. My problem is the formula

A = Rc / re

makes things so much different than designing same circuit without it. I already designed one with gain of 5 in less than a hour but I am stuck in this one.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: It will be max V gain with wide tolerances on gain dependant on hFE, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a genuine common emitter configuration (emitter at AC ground), the small-signal open-circuit voltage gain is approximately

$$A_{voc} = -g_m \cdot R_C||r_o \approx-g_mR_C = -\frac{I_CR_C}{V_T} = -\frac{V_{CC} - V_C}{V_T}$$

Thus, the AC gain is *fixed* by your choice of supply voltage \$V_{CC}\$ and DC collector voltage \$V_C\$

If, like many, you choose (or require that) \$V_C = \frac{V_{CC}}{2}\$, the gain of the (genuine) common emitter amplifier is just

$$A_{voc} \approx -\frac{V_{CC}}{2V_T}$$

Which is to say that you don't have the necessary degree of freedom to *choose* the AC gain independent of the supply voltage.

Now, by adding a resistor \$R_4\$ in series \$C_4\$, you *gain* the degree of freedom for the AC gain:

$$A_{voc} \approx -\frac{\alpha R_C}{r_e + R_4||R_7} $$

where

$$r_e = \frac{V_T}{I_E}$$

Assuming once again that you choose \$I_CR_C = \frac{V_{CC}}{2}\$, the AC gain is:

$$A_{voc} \approx -\frac{V_{CC}}{2(V_T + I_E\cdot R_4||R_7)} $$

Answer (score 1):

This is high gain and used for low level (1mV) signals.  *Rbe* becomes the emitter resistance , determined by the DC base current.  Add another small R in series with C4 to obtain a higher fixed gain such that it is > Rbe.

This gain with a 2nd Re must be less than gain achieved with max gain as shown.
Optimal voltage gain depends on tradeoff of lowering input impedance of Re by adding more base current and impedance of load. Thus if one wants to reduce load resistance, collector R must be less <= load R and then to reduce Rbe, input impedance must also drop by increasing Ib bias current.

If one is only using AC coupled signals, extra output swing can be achieved using an inductor for Rc, and raise operating point of Vc=V+.  The impedance of collector choke being higher than R load, results in all the ac current and voltage gain going into the load, at the expense of more DC power. Gain is just the R ratios again above breakpoint range of f.  Thus large voltage gains of 1k are possible for RF with large output swings using inductor on collector, controlled gains with a 2nd R in series with C.  In short, many variations with stable results for explicit source/load signals.

Comment: To be sure, adding a resistor in series with C4 results in a *lower* fixed gain.

Comment: Yes, As any degenerative feedback loop reduces open loop gain to obtain stability of gain with R ratio, it is usually an acceptable tradeoff. Gain can be easily calculated but lower, just as in Op Amps. Voltage gains also depends on current gain and admittance gain from source to load.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what your problem really is.
Is it the expression Rc/re?

OK - in your case we have Rc=R8.

And what is re? It is the inverse of the transistor´s transconductance gm=1/re.
(I must confess, that I don´t like the term re. In fact, it is NOT a resistance as can be seen from its definition: gm=1/re).

Because the BJT is a voltage controlled current source it is quite logical to use the transconductance gm which is a measure of the slope of the transfer function Ic=f(Vbe).
This results in the gain expression

**A=-gm*Rc/(1+gm*RE)**  RE: external emitter resistor.

If (as in your) case RE is shunted by a capacitor we have RE||CE~0 (for large freqencies) and

**A=-gm*Rc.**

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: \$r_e = \frac{V_T}{I_E} = \frac{\alpha}{g_m}\$; it is the small-signal (dynamic) intrinsic emitter resistance in the BJT T-model.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear about the issue. I am end up with 300 ohm Rc value when I assume Ic as 1mA, calculate the re and calculate Rc based on Av I need. That small value conflicts with the Ic I need. Lets say I want to have Vcc/2 as VRc (in my case 4.5) the Ic becomes 15 mA.

This is my confusion point, I cant have too high Rc because of Av I need (which is 30) and also cant have low Rc value because of it s effect on Ic.

How can I calculate the values at this point?

Comment: @dvdnhm, as I explained in my answer, you don't have the degree of freedom to independently choose the AC gain once you've selected the DC collector voltage.  This is why you're unable to find a solution that satisfies \$V_C = \frac{V_{CC}}{2}\$ *and* \$A_v = -30\$.